# how can i delete the s3 object from Node mongo by use location url?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, mern

i have posted tha pdf file to s3 bucket and save the return Location Url path of file in mongodb . so now i want to delete that file data by get mongoid file location url path from mongodb.im not understanding how can i get the aws parms by url path and how can i delete both??. so please help me any one how can i  delete this file??

```
router.delete('/:epdfurl',  async function(req, res,next) {
const id = req.params.epdfurl;
   const params2 = {
        Bucket:bucketName2,
        Key:file.booksEpdf[0].originalname,
        Body:file.booksEpdf[0].buffer,
            acl: 'public-read'
        };
        s3.deleteObject(params2,(error,data)=>{
        if(error){
            res.status(500).send({"err":error})
        }
        const data2=data
            console.log(data2)
        S3Epdf.remove({ _id: id })
            .exec()
            .then(result => {
                res.send(result)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.send(err)
            })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to pass the Body in your `params2`. Mind you though, the Key should be the full path to the object inside your s3 bucket. eg: `path/to/file/my_file.pdf`

Comment: thanks for answer.but how can i specify the path of s3 single object by take location Url from mongo

Comment: now im getting this error in postmen

Comment: {
    "message": "There were 3 validation errors:\n* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'Key' in params\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'location' found in params\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'key' found in params",
    "code": "MultipleValidationErrors",
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Missing required key 'Key' in params",
            "code": "MissingRequiredParameter",
            "time": "2021-12-15T06:07:58.388Z"
        }